# Can not execute Robot Framework Properly (No module name Robot)

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I had update Robot Framework into the newer version
Here are pip list that I had already download

```
Package                         Version
------------------------------- -----------
Appium-Python-Client            0.49
certifi                         2020.6.20
chardet                         3.0.4
decorator                       4.4.2
django-robots                   4.0
docutils                        0.16
idna                            2.10
kitchen                         1.2.6
numpy                           1.19.1
Pillow                          7.2.0
pip                             19.0.3
Pygments                        2.6.1
PyPubSub                        3.3.0
pywin32                         228
requests                        2.24.0
robot                           20071211
robotframework                  3.2.1
robotframework-appiumlibrary    1.5.0.4
robotframework-databaselibrary  1.2.4
robotframework-pythonlibcore    2.1.0
robotframework-requests         0.7.1
robotframework-ride             1.7.3.1
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  3.3.1
robotframeworklexer             1.1
selenium                        3.141.0
setuptools                      40.8.0
six                             1.15.0
urllib3                         1.25.10
wxPython                        4.0.7.post2
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Python that I chosen is 3.7.4

However, I need to executes the script, which it should be execute normally. However, I found that it caught error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Scripts\robot.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robot'
```

that I don't understand that cause of error.
I have already got robot files as well

Comment: robot.exe is the name of the application, not for a folder. I don't understand why the program catch robot.exe into path?

Comment: Because robot.exe is made for an underlying Python file in which the ModuleNotFoundError happens.

Comment: How do you start the Robot Framework script? `python -m robot`?

Comment: Yes, when I start, i caught error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "D:\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\lib\site-packages\robot\__main__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from robot import run_cli
ImportError: cannot import name 'run_cli' from 'robot' (D:\lib\site-packages\robot\__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution yet? I doubt if your command to execute robot is correct.
`robot <Path to robot file>` will execute it.
for example  `robot Tests/my_robot_test.robot` and if you have tags assigned, you can run specific tag test cases with `robot -i <tag_id> Tests/my_robot_test.robot`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for anyone looking in the future:

I've noticed you have a package called `robot` installed and Python for whatever reason checks that first and does not look after the executable from the package `robotframework`.

So just `python -m pip uninstall robot` and everything should work again.

Or at least that fixed it for me.